# Would it rain in Florida during thanksgiving?

Tags: usa, weather-and-climate, florida, thanksgiving

I've been googling and do not yet have a clear answer. We have about 7 days of holidays during thanksgiving, and our choices are Florida and Colorado. (We're from Dallas, Texas).

I heard Colorado is quite frozen at that time of the year, and we probably may not have much to do for 6-7 days! Just wanted to know if Florida is gonna be rainy.

Comment: You could get anything from clear and sunny all week to a hurricane.

Comment: Colorado won't necessarily be frozen. I hosted a Thanksgiving at my place in Denver a few years ago and it was mid-50's. We actually get most of our snow in February. They say that if you don't like the weather, just wait 5 minutes....

Comment: What is your definition of "quite frozen".  While the night time lows are below the freezing point of water, the [average daily high temps in Denver are in the 50's F](http://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/denver/colorado/united-states/usco0105) for the month of November.  Certainly not as warm as Florida on average, it is a far cry from freezing cold unless you are used to extremely hot temps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is debating about a future event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Winters in Florida can be relatively dry as most significant rain is supposed to be over by onset of Fall. However, as a tropical, coastal state, Florida is always subject to the possibility of rains, so there is no way to guarantee there wont be rain during Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 6):

[Weatherspark's averages page for Orlando](https://weatherspark.com/averages/30841/Orlando-Florida-United-States) indicates that in late November there is typically a ~30% chance of rain on any given day. For [Panama City](https://weatherspark.com/averages/30137/Panama-City-Florida-United-States) up in the panhandle, the chance is lower at 20% but I would still expect rain at some point if you're there for a week.